# Como usar la funciones de un script en otro con unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Tengo el siguiente problema: te un script en **unity** (C#) el cual me establece una conexión con la bd. Lo provee de solo, en un **GameObject** y sin problema me trabaja colocando el método con el nombre **Start**, puedo ver sin problema los registro de la bd. El problema me viene cuando le cambio el nombre al método por ***Dbcontec*** y lo trato de llamar en otro script en el momento de compilar me genera un error. A continuación les dejo el código de los script para ver si me pueden ayudar.

> Conexión con la base de datos.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System;
using System.Data;
using Mono.Data.Sqlite;

namespace Dbconection {
    public class Dbcnx : MonoBehaviour {

        public int Idrow;

        // Use this for initialization
        public void Dbcontec () {

            string conn = "URI=file:" + Application.dataPath + "/db_cuentos.s3db"; //Path to database.
            IDbConnection dbconn;
            dbconn = (IDbConnection) new SqliteConnection(conn);
            dbconn.Open(); //Open connection to the database.
            IDbCommand dbcmd = dbconn.CreateCommand();

            string sqlQuery = "SELECT * " + "FROM data_cuent Where id = '"+Idrow+"'";
            dbcmd.CommandText = sqlQuery;
            IDataReader reader = dbcmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                int id = reader.GetInt32(0);
                string nombre = reader.GetString(1);
                //int rand = reader.GetInt32(2);

                Debug.Log( "id= "+id+"  nombre ="+nombre);
            }
            reader.Close();
            reader = null;
            dbcmd.Dispose();
            dbcmd = null;
            dbconn.Close();
            dbconn = null;

        }
    }

}
```

> Script donde estoy llamando la conexión

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Dbconection;

public class Inicio : MonoBehaviour {

    public Dbcnx dbcnx;
    public int Idrow;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        dbcnx.Dbcontec();

    }
}
```

**Error que se me genera.**

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
>   Inicio.Start () (at Assets/Inicio.cs:13)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Necesitas instanciar la clase antes de llamar al método:

```
public Dbcnx dbcnx = new Dbcnx();
```

Comment: La respuesta es correcta. Agregaria solo a titulo de aclaración que si no instancias la clase, la misma esta en null y provoca exactamente ese error.